# Path JRE on VSCode MacOS

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, sonarlint, sonarlint-vs

What is the correct path of JRE8 that I put in `sonarlint.ls.javaHome` in VSCode in MacOS so that it works correctly?

I have tried this:

`\\Library\\Internet Plug-Ins\\JavaAppletPlugin.plugin\\Contents\\Home\\bin`
`/Library/Internet\\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/`

Comment: The path correct is: `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home`

Comment: post it as answer and accept ;)

Comment: Has anyone found an answer to this yet? I am facing the exact same issue - VSCode (Version 1.23.1) in macOS (High Sierra Version 10.13.4). I have tried all of the following values for the "sonarlint.js.javaHome" variable with no success:

- "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/"
- "/Library/Java/Home"
- "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/"
- "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/"

Comment: @Dib , I see that you install JRE 10 and this doesn't work. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Install JDK and set "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home" in VSCODE settings under sonarlint.ls.javaHome

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have the same issue and there is one important message: you must use JRE8 and not the newest version of JRE (e.g. JRE 10) for the plugin "SonarLint" (sonarsource.sonarlint-vscode). With JRE9 or newer it doesn't work!

This path worked for me:

`"sonarlint.ls.javaHome": "/Library/Internet PlugIns/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home"`